# Proving uniform convergence of a function sequence.

Tags: uniform-convergence

I was asked to check whether $f_n(x)= n(\sin(x+\frac{1}{n}) -\sin x )$ convergence uniformly  in $\mathbb{R}$.
So I found the limit function $f(x) = \cos x $ and I tired to prove that $$ \underset{x \in \mathbb{R}}{\text{sup}}\{|f_n(x)-f(x)|\}\xrightarrow[]{n \rightarrow \infty} 0 $$

with some trigonometric identities but with no success. I would to get a hint or some help. Thanks!

Comment: Are you dealing with a series or with a sequence?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Many thanks, but unfortunately, we don't learn Cauchy's criterion in this course :(

Comment: What has that to do with the duplicate question?

Comment: @AnotherUser Thanks, didn't know the difference between the two in English. I fixed it.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Oops. Didn't read it correctly, my bad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f_n(x)=2n\sin\frac{1}{2n}\cos(x+\frac{1}{2n})$.Therefore $|f(x)-f_n(x)|=|2n\sin\frac{1}{2n}\cos(x+\frac{1}{2n})-\cos x|\leq\\|2n\sin\frac{1}{2n}(\cos(x+\frac{1}{2n})-\cos x)|+|\cos x(2n\sin\frac{1}{2n}-1)|$.

Only need to show right hand side $\to 0$.This can be easily done from $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}2n\sin\frac{1}{2n}=1$.